# vbscript and UFT

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

```
dim ExcelObj, WorkBook, WorkSheet, Value, i, j,d,  myarray()
j=0

set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObj.Visible = true
set WorkBook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open ("\\calbcdata.molina.mhc\IS\OM\Test Automation\Chaitanya\response.xls")
set WorkSheet = WorkBook.Worksheets ("response")


For i= 2 to 5

If FormatDateTime(Worksheet.cells(i, 13).value, 2)=date() then
myarray(j)=Worksheet.cells(i, 6).value
j=j+1
msgbox myarray(j)

End If

Next
```

This is code snippet I tried to executed on HP-UFT.  This is just to get the email ID of a row which has date as today's date
Its not entering into "IF" why?

Comment: Even if it goes inside the If condition, it is going to throw you an error. You are not redeclaring the array with new dimensions using "Redim". The first line inside the If condition should be: Redim preserve myarray(j)

Comment: What is the format of dates stored in excel? Is it mm/dd/yy or dd/mm/yy?

Comment: It is mm/dd/yy only. Ill try go with the suggestion given. Another thing is that I tried to use aqDateTime.Compare(Date1, Date2) just to replace the above comparison. It says Object should be present. what does it mean?

Comment: Not sure about the aqObject. Just try to get the value of FormatDateTime(Worksheet.cells(2, 13).value, 2) using msgbox. Post the value here.

Comment: This is the value 5/30/2017

Comment: Not sure if the date being fetched from  the excel is stored in a string or not. If it is of type string, then there will be a mismatch. So, inside the if condition use cdate(FormatDateTime(Worksheet.cells(i, 13).value, 2)) instead of just FormatDateTime(Worksheet.cells(i, 13).value, 2).

Comment: Yaa, kira is right. from Excel it will fetch the value as string and you have to convert it in Date format using Cdate funtion and if u don't use Redim preserve myarray(j) before myaaray(j) = worksheet.cells(i,6).value then you will get subscript out of range error. follow both the steps said by @kira . code will work.

Comment: Thanks its working

Comment: What changes did you make? Did it start working after converting the data fetched from excel to type date using CDate?